# Salesforce apex - how to determine if a field is set to be tracked in Chatter?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I'm writing triggers / classes to post field change notifications to the Chatter feeds of objects related to the object undergoing change (e.g. posting a field update of an Opportunity to its related Account is changed).

I've written the code to compare the before and after values and post feed updates for the values that have changed just fine.  But I only want to post updates for fields that are set to be "tracked" in Chatter (Setup -> Customize -> Chatter -> Feed Tracking).

How can I get at these settings in Apex?

(It's possible to call isFeedEnabled() on an object to see if Chatter is enabled for that object.  But I don't see any way to tell if an individual field is set to have its updates posted to the feed)

Cheers,
Ray

Answer (score 0):

There's call like isFeedEnabled() for checking on field-level tracking (both for chatter and the old style field history) sadly.

You could however use a trigger on the feedItem sObject to see if an item where Type == 'FeedTrackedChange' is created, and if so query the FeedTrackedChanges related to that FeedItem; then create the chatter post from there.

Comment: [For Another User] Per http://media.developerforce.com/cheatsheets/SF_chatter_4Pg_HR.pdf, 
FeedItem triggers only fire when Type is in TextPost, LinkPost, and ContentPost.